# Monitor color profile cannot be applied after Creators update

Tags: windows-10, color-profiles, windows-10-v1703

Everything was fine up until yesterday when I've installed the Creators update. Right after logging into Windows after the update I noticed that the colors are all wrong on my monitor. That's because it's pretty awful out of the box, and I have a color profile to fix that created with Spyder4 colorimeter/profiler.

So I went to Color Management to re-apply the profile, thinking that I just need to select the correct default profile. But no. Some time after opening Color Management, or when browsing its nested dialogs, I eventually get a pop-up:

> The Devices pages has been refreshed due to a hardware change.

It keeps appearing periodically. The Color Management UI functions normally, I can add/remove profiles and set them as default, except it has literally no effect whatsoever.

**However**: if I simply launch and exit the Spyder4 application, the default profile (the one I set as default in Color Management) does get applied and it sticks until reboot. After that, I no longer get the "Devices pages has been refreshed" pop-up. Again, until reboot.

What could be wrong and how to fix it?